# Error setting attributes for 1 product not every product

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have an issue where when I create an attribute/configurable, it gets set on every product and I just want them on one specific product, instead of every product I create having all these attributes I created.

For example:

250g/ 500g/ 1kg/ 2kg

but then every product gets this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Create attribute set for specific product like if you want to create product "custom protein powder" then also create attribute set for custom protein powder and make sure you have created attribute set before product creation. 
and assign all three attributes only to "custom protein powder" attribute set
and when you create product just select "custom protein powder" as your attribute set.
Done!!